# RDP from firewalled corporate network to Azure?

Tags: firewall, azure, rdp

I'm working my company's network security on opening up access to reach Azure VMs which will be a mix of Windows and Linux. Outbound RDP from the corporate network is blocked by default. They are asking for a whitelist of IPs/FQDNs. Rather than having to update this list every time I spin up a new VM, what's the best practice I should follow? I've seen jump boxes recommended, but would that not restrict access to a single user at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options here:

1. Approve access to all Azure IP ranges, either globally or for specific regions Microsoft publish and regularly update the IP ranges [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=azure%20IP%20ranges&oq=azure%20IP%20ranges&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60l3j0.3798j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
2. Look at making a private connection to Azure via VPN or Express Route, so you can white list RDP access over that connection
3. Utilize a jump box, or multiple jump boxes and white list the jumpbox IP. You can have multiple users using the same jump box so long as you use a server OS and purchase RDS client access licences

Comment: For option 3, can the jump box be a pretty tiny VM?

Comment: yes, and you can have 2 sessions by default to that VM.  You can also set shutdown times to ensure it is shut down after hours